# ошибка при запуске uiautomatorviewer

Tags: android-studio, appium

при запуске из командной строки uiautomatorviewer, выдаёт ошибку:

-Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

я поменял версию java SDK с 19-ой на 8-ю, для этого нужно зарегистрироваться в Oracle, но на данный момент приходится использовать VPN для скачивания установщика.